# Codecept Hidden field

Tags: codeception

My Form contain a hidden field `csrf` and  my `Controller` has a method to check `CSRF` attack. In my `functional test`, I tried by `fillField` to check my `Controller's method` redirect to specific page if someone `temper form`. I read somewhere that `codecept` works only with visible field.

#### Is there is any way that I can fill a hidden field in `functional` or `acceptance` test?

Answer (score 2):

This is the only system which worked for me :

```
$I->executeJS('$(".yourMethodClass").val("YOUR_VALUE_HERE");');
```

Of course u can call it by ID or any javascript selectors u want.

Comment: this only works of you are using WebDriver and not PhpBrowser

Comment: It cannot be used in functional test. The solution of @MatějRačinský is best.

Answer (score 1):

You can use fillField for hidden inputs. I use it in my tests and it works just fine, it properly fills value of hidden input.

```
$I->fillField(['name' => 'email'], 'some email');
$I->fillField(['name' => 'password'], 'myPassword');

$I->fillField('privilegesList','read'); //this is hidden input
$I->click('submit button');
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, a way around this:

> **Before filling your hidden input execute a jquery command to show that input:**

```
$I->executeJS('$(".req").show();'); 
$I->fillField('inputWebHidden', 'some-value');
```

> - Replace '.req' with your field class/id/whatever.
> - Note that I use PhantomJS server, and the exception thrown: **[Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\InvalidElementStateException]**
> - I understand this might considered a hack. But for the purposes of a honey pot, it's fine.

Comment: this only works of you are using WebDriver and not PhpBrowser

Comment: You do not need anymore to update your field before filling. The solution of Matej works with PhpBrowser and in functional test.

Answer (score -1):

You can use submitForm() to submit hidden form values:

```
$I->submitForm('#id_of_form', array(
    'hidden_field_name' => 'value_to_submit'
));
```

But I think you're right, you can't use `fillField()`  or similar methods.

Comment: Does not work. From the documentationof submitForm(): Submits the given form on the page, optionally with the given form values.  Give the form fields values as an array. **Note that hidden fields can't be accessed.**